# Python default argument referencing previous argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

This might not be a great question, but is something like this possible in any way using Python 3.x?

```py
def test_func(x, y=x):
  return
```

It's not a big deal to test for y, and reassign if necessary, but just curious about this.

Comment: Absolutely impossible.  In Python, default values are calculated *once*, at the time the function was defined; there was no value for `x` at that point in time.

Comment: No. Just use `y=None` in the signature and in the body of the function, `if y is None: y = x`