# Nextcord Dynamically Get Choices

Tags: python, nextcord

I am trying to use nextcord to get all the choices from a user's inventory, but I am having trouble getting the user_id for my fetch_choices function. See below for some more details.

My slash command looks like this, (... is where I want userid):

```py
async def duel(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, item: str = nextcord.SlashOption("item", choices=fetch_choices(...)), quantity: int = 1, side: str = "h"):
```

This is my fetch_choices code:

```py
def fetch_choices(user_id):
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM items WHERE user_id=?", (user_id,))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    items = {}
    for row in rows:
        item = row[1],
        items.update({item[0]: item[0]})
    return items
```

My question is how can I get the user id, and pass it to fetch_choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible at the moment. It would be great if we could somehow pass the interaction into the `SlashOption` class and use it to generate a different default value for every user, but as a comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68321587/python-default-argument-referencing-previous-argument) states, default values in python are calculated one time. Ideally, nextcord would allow us to provide a callback function, which could generate these options on-the-fly for each interaction, but that feature doesn't exist yet.

**BUT**

We can get *almost* the same experience by using the autocomplete feature, instead of `choices`:

```
async def duel(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, item: str = nextcord.SlashOption("item"), quantity: int = 1, side: str = "h"):
   pass

@duel.on_autocomplete("item")
async def item_autocomplete(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, item: str):
    choices = fetch_choices(interaction.user.id, item)
    await interaction.response.send_autocomplete(choices)

def fetch_choices(user_id, name_substr=''):
    pattern = f'%{name_substr}%'
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM items WHERE user_id=? AND name LIKE ?", (user_id, pattern))
    rows = c.fetchall()
    items = []
    for row in rows:
        items.append(row[1])
    return items
```

A couple caveats:

1. The `fetch_choices` function will run every time a character is typed into the slash option. If number of queries isn't an issue, this is probably fine. Otherwise, some caching might be a good idea.
2. If any items contain the `%` character (or any other special sqlite pattern characters), `pattern = f'%{name_substr}%'` might not always work. There are other options, like using [`instr`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr), but I figured I'd give the simplest solution first.

At the time of writing, this works *almost* exactly the same as providing choices to `SlashOption`. However, it takes a bit longer for the options to appear, and there is no error for invalid items, since autocomplete is just a suggestion. Of course, you can handle invalid arguments in your slash function, but you won't get the nice red box that discord displays for an invalid `SlashOption`.

[image: screenshot of discord text input showing a slash option configured with autocomplete with a normal border, and a slash option configured with choices with a red border]

Comment: Ill test this, thank you for the effort. If it does work ill award the bounty.

Comment: Thank you so much, works perfectly. Exactly how I wanted.

Comment: Glad to help! Happy hacking!